React-leaflet image overlay always as a background regardless of resolutions?
Im having problems with ImageOverlay inside react leaflet, I want to have an image with fixed aspect ratio always be background and not be able to be zoomed out of it, but using fitbounds or restricting with maxbounds isnt enough, on different resolutions the zooms are different, same with bounds, if I set fixed zooms I have completly different bounds and zooms set by default and the image gets scaled on different aspect ratios, my question is how am I supposed to have an ImageOverlay always be 100 width and height and if its not possible them simply zoom inside(Same way object-fit cover behaves)
Tried using fitbounds or dynamically setting zooms but on certain aspect ratios it doesnt work...

In this case I think you need to share your code for others to better understand your issue.
